# Symlink ~.zshrc

Tags: zsh

If my .zshrc file is ~/.dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc, how can I create a symlink so that the file appears as ~/.zshrc?

Answer (score 31):

The `cd` step in Alexej's answer isn't needed as you can call ln -s *target destination* explicitly.

```
ln -s ~/.dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 3):

run:

```
cd ~/ ; ln -s ~/.dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc
```

Comment: I get a ~/.zshrc: No such file or directory error. Why is this?

Comment: I dunno, but you could try going into your home directory--that is, `cd ~`--and try running this from there `ln -s ~/.dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc`

Comment: I think, I know now.  Mac OSX's `ln` doesn't have the `-T` option, my bad.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for me, when using relative path for symlink, it can show error:  `~/.zshrc: No such file or directory error` as @astephen2. You should change to absolute path then it working fine

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, you can't use `~` in a symlink where the directory is quoted. You need to use full paths. I'd recommend running `ln -s "$HOME/.dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc" "$HOME/.zshrc"` Alternatively, you can forget the quotes, and use `~` in place of `$HOME`, however if there are any spaces (or variables with spaces) you'll probably run into problems.

Comment: You can still use `~` in the *arguments* to `ln -s`, though; the shell expands them before `ln` is executed.

Comment: You're right, I had originally forgotten to mention that that only happens when using quotes, because the shell won't replace the `~`

Comment: You can quote any portion of the path, if necessary, while leaving `~` unquoted: `~/"$SOMEDIR"/.zshrc` expands correctly.

Comment: Oh... that completely escaped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a symlink. Add the following to `~/.zshenv`:

```
ZDOTDIR=~/.dotfiles/zsh
```

`zsh` sources `~/.zshenv` before any other files, and will use the value of `$ZDOTDIR` as the location for local configuration files in lieu of your home directory.